# Hiren's Boot CD - HDD Diagnostics - EDIT S.M.A.R.T. info

Tags: hard-drive, bad-sectors

I have a Seagate hard drive and scanned it using Hiren Boot CD with HDD Revitalizer.

HDD Revitalizer scanned and repaired bad blocks. It only found 2 bad sectors.

After that I ran a low level format. I know this will not change S.M.A.R.T data or HDD Revitalizer.

I repeated HDD Revitalizer and it did not find any bad sectors, and the hard drive works fine now.

However, S.M.A.R.T. showed 32 reallocated sector counts, and repaired them as well. *[??? Grammar too bad to fix. Sentence is incoherent.]* There aren't any new bad sectors.

I want to relocate "Sectors Count" in the S.M.A.R.T chip, by changing from 32 to 0, because now there are no bad sectors.

Tools like Ubuntu disks or HDD Disk Sentinel shows 32 bad sectors. HDD Revitalizer shows different info.

So, how can i change a data in S.M.A.R.T on Seagate from 2008. year of 250 GB hdd? Is that good idea to change value from 32 to 0?

Comment: I fixed your grammar with the exception of a completely incoherent sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't edit this: relocated sector count means the drive found some bad sectors and relocated them to a pool of spare (good) sectors so the drive can keep functioning. However, this also means your drive is going bad: the bad sectors are not repaired, just reallocated. I think you should backup any important data on the disk and replace it.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.#Known_ATA_S.M.A.R.T._attributes for an explanation of SMART attributes

Answer (score -1):

32 reallocated sectors is an insignificant amount and would not warrant a disk replacement.

If pending and uncorrectable sectors are on the rise in relatively short time period it is a different story.

This disk is 10 years old, only 523 reallocated sectors. Drive is healthy. It has, and is still running in a ZFS pool.

I have a disk of similar model with 1700 reallocated sectors, disk checks failed.

Below 1000 reallocated is just fine.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CijDE.png)